# How to remove Chromebook utility recovery

Tags: applications, drivers

Hi I just installed  elementary OS the stable version today I found 2  application that I can't remove Chromebook utility recovery and hangout ... How can removed from my system .. also the touch pad is no responding when I tap on it I'm using a Lenovo 100s 80R9